# NullPointerExeption Android. retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Пишу активити, при вызове которого приосходит следующее:
С помощью библиотеки retrofit на сервер делается GET запрос с параметром. В ответ нам приходит массив объектов
Я описал для них модель, api. Метод который все это делает. в методе onCreate выношу в отдельный поток создание запроса, и в строчке

```
users = api.users(jwtToken);
```

вместо того что бы заполнить массив, Он переходит в файл RuntimeInit.java и выполняет этот метод

```
public boolean onException(Object obj, Throwable e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Приложение крашится с ошибкой NullPointerExeption
Хотя, как мне кажется, все инициализировано.
Код привожу ниже

```
    package com.sancho.clienttest;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import retrofit.http.Body;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Header;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;


public class SuccessLog extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView text;
    TextView uInfo;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    SharedPreferences sToken;
    user [] users;
    String jwtToken;

    public class user {
        private String id;
        private String username;
        private String email;
        private String group;
        private String sex;
        private String avatar;
        private String firstname;
        private String secondname;

        public user(String id, String username, String email, String group,String sex,String avatar, String firstname, String secondname){
            this.id = id;
            this.username = username;
            this.email = email;
            this.group = group;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.avatar = avatar;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.secondname = secondname;
        }

        public user(){}

        public String getId() {return id;}
        public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}
        public String getUsername() {return username;}
        public void setUsername(String username) {this.username = username;}
        public String getEmail() {return email;}
        public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
        public String getGroup(){return group;}
        public void setGroup(String group) {this.group = group;}
        public String getSex() {return sex;}
        public void setSex(String sex) {this.sex = sex;}
        public String getAvatar() {return avatar;}
        public void setAvatar(String avatar) {this.avatar = avatar;}
        public String getFirstname() {return firstname;}
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {this.firstname = firstname;}
        public String getSecondname() {return secondname;}
        public void setSecondname(String secondname) {this.secondname = secondname;}



    }

    public interface Api{
        public static final String URL ="http://178.62.42.66/api/v1";
        static final String USERS = "/users/";


        @GET(USERS)
       user [] users(@Header("Authorization") String jwtToken );

    }

    private void getUsers(String jwtToken){
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Api.URL)
                .build();
        Api api = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
        users = api.users(jwtToken);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.success_log);
        AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
        aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://178.62.42.66/static/images/avatars/default_avatar.png");
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        uInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString("token","");
        jwtToken = "JWT "+savedText;


        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                getUsers(jwtToken);
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();


       // user [] users;
        uInfo.setText(users[0].getUsername()); //users[0].getUsername();
        text.setText(savedText);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_success_log, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ЛОГИ ниже

```
04-22 19:10:13.212    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11434: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11440: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9116: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
04-22 19:10:13.244    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
04-22 19:10:13.248    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-22 19:10:13.248    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 404: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-22 19:10:13.248    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-22 19:10:13.248    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-22 19:10:13.248    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 426: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-22 19:10:13.248    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-22 19:10:13.300    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
04-22 19:10:13.304    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8798b68, tid 1102
04-22 19:10:13.324    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
04-22 19:10:13.324    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
04-22 19:10:13.372    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-22 19:10:13.384    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-22 19:10:19.488    1102-1105/com.sancho.clienttest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 177K, 3% free 8820K/9024K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 6ms
04-22 19:10:19.544    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-22 19:10:28.356    1102-1105/com.sancho.clienttest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 264K, 4% free 8944K/9236K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 3ms
04-22 19:10:28.380    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-22 19:10:28.380    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6223908)
04-22 19:10:28.380    1102-1102/com.sancho.clienttest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sancho.clienttest/com.sancho.clienttest.SuccessLog}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sancho.clienttest.SuccessLog.onCreate(SuccessLog.java:119)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос логи (stacktrace ошибки). В текущем виде непонятно, где именно возникает ошибка.

Comment: @fori1ton добавил логи

Answer (score 1):

NPE получается на строке `uInfo.setText(users[0].getUsername());`

Данный код:

> ```
> uInfo.setText(users[0].getUsername()); //users[0].getUsername();
> text.setText(savedText);
> ```

должен выполняться после завершения запроса, а не до него.

Посмотрите в сторону `AsyncTask` для запуска кода в отдельном потоке или сразу посмотрите связку [Robospice+Retrofit](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Retrofit-module)

Comment: а разве в это строчке не идет заполнение?
 users = api.users(jwtToken);
В onCreate вызывается функция getUsers, внутри которой происходит заполнение массива users, собственно строчка 
 users = api.users(jwtToken);

Comment: @AlexandrGnatyuk `getUsers()` запускается в отдельном потоке, и поток не успеет дойти до заполнения раньше, чем вызовется получение

Comment: а не подскажете как можно это исправить? Если убрать все, что связано с "'Thread'", т.е. с вынесением в отдельный поток, то приложение продолжает крашится.

Comment: @AlexandrGnatyuk в этом случае возникает исключение `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, которое не дает использовать в главном потоке запросы к сети (и это правильно). Посмотрите на Robospice, это готовое решение большей части проблем при взаимодействии с API